# Error 0xc0204016: SSIS.Pipeline: The length that is not valid. The length must be between 0 and 4000

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I have a sql database file in file format of MDF. I installed and opened the MDF file in SQL server and used SSMS to export data to Excel file but I am getting following error.

[image]

What are the possible solution to solve the char length issue.

Comment: show us the package, and where the failure is

Comment: prolly due to one of the connectors settings being off

Comment: Which package ?

Comment: the ssis package? wanting to see the control flow to see if i can help you pinpoint the issue

Comment: also see if this helps. you might have to manually change values on the export  http://www.thesqlreport.com/?p=837

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by SSIS package.

[I am using this tutorial to open SQL database.](https://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-can-i-open-mdf-and-ldf-files-in-sql-server-attach-tutorial-troublshooting/)

Comment: Yes I have saw that post already but in that post they are using csv to import data. in my case it is Excel file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238334/discussion-between-abdulsamad-and-doug-coats).